# JavaScript: merge multiple object arrays by index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanted to merge multi-array of objects below

`[{"genderid":1515},{"genderid":1516},{"genderid":1513}]`

`[{"modnameid":1515},{"modnameid":1516},{"modnameid":1514}]`

to the desired output below

```
[
  {"genderid":1515,"modnameid":1515},
  {"genderid":1516,"modnameid":1516},
  {"genderid":1513,"modnameid":1514}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to merge two arrays of objects according to the `index`:

- Check which one of the two is greater than the other, and set each to `first` and `second` accordingly (`first` should be iterated over to guarantee the element at `index` won't be `undefined`)
- Iterate over `first` using `.map`, and merge the two objects at each index

```js
const mergeTwoArraysByIndex = (arr1=[], arr2=[]) => {

  // get larger of the two to iterate over
  let first = [], second = [];
  if(arr1.length > arr2.length) { first = arr1; second = arr2; }
  else { first = arr2; second = arr1; }
  
  // merge two arrays
  const merged = first.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, ...second[index] }));
  
  return merged;
}

console.log( 
  mergeTwoArraysByIndex(
    [{"genderid":1515},{"genderid":1516},{"genderid":1513}],
    [{"modnameid":1515},{"modnameid":1516},{"modnameid":1514}]
  )
);
console.log( 
  mergeTwoArraysByIndex(
    [{"genderid":1515},{"genderid":1516}],
    [{"modnameid":1515},{"modnameid":1516},{"modnameid":1514}]
  )
);
console.log( 
  mergeTwoArraysByIndex(
    [{"genderid":1515},{"genderid":1516},{"genderid":1513}],
    [{"modnameid":1515},{"modnameid":1516}]
  )
);
```

**Update:**
If you want to merge multiple arrays in this fasion:

```js
const mergeArraysByIndex = (arrays=[], merged=[], index=0) => {

  // stop when last array is reached
  if(index >= arrays.length) return merged;
  
  // get larger of the two to iterate over
  const arr1 = merged, arr2 = arrays[index] || [];
  let first = [], second = [];
  if(arr1.length > arr2.length) { first = arr1; second = arr2; } 
  else { first = arr2; second = arr1; }
  
  // merge two arrays
  merged = first.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, ...second[index] }) );
  
  return mergeArraysByIndex(arrays, merged, index+1);
}

console.log( 
  mergeArraysByIndex(
    [
      [{"genderid":1515},{"genderid":1516}],
      [{"modnameid":1515},{"modnameid":1516},],
      [{"userid":1515},{"userid":1516},{"userid":1514}]
    ]
  )
);
console.log( 
  mergeArraysByIndex(
    [
      [{"genderid":1515},{"genderid":1516}],
      [{"modnameid":1515},{"modnameid":1516},],
      [{"userid":1515},{"userid":1516},{"userid":1514}],
      [{"ageid":1515},{"ageid":1516},{"ageid":1514},{"ageid":1515}]
    ]
  )
);
```

Comment: there is high possibility that there is would length issue in the implementation stage in my case scenarios, however this  spot on solution  position if length constraint was not there, is there any solution discarding length solutions ! thanks again

Comment: @RizwanPatel yes this should be handeled, answer updated

Comment: thanks for package and considering the case scenarios , this should suffice for two array of objects which was my question .However just out of curiosity if we say more then two array to merge say for e.g 5-6 arrray to merge in same fashion how do we go about it reason for dynamic array gen is basically I am building bolierplate https://github.com/matt212/Nodejs_Postgresql_VanillaJS_Fastify/tree/containerX

Comment: @RizwanPatel I updated the answer with a possible approach to the problem you stated, out of curiosity as well :)

Comment: thanks again for placing solutions for multi-array case scenarios you sir,  @majed  is  awesome!